# Не работает кнопка в Contact Form 7

Tags: html, wordpress, css, javascript

Не могу понять, в чем проблема. Кнопка в форме не нажимается. При этом никаких ошибок не выдает.
Плагин для **Wordpress - Contact Form 7**. [Сайт](http://politech.kz).

Comment: Где форма-то? Не вижу.

Comment: http://politech.kz/kontakty/

Answer (score 1):

1. Я зашел на сайт, и все формы, которые нашел, были рабочие.
2. Включите на сайте дебаг режим и посмотрите, где и какие ошибки появляются. Скорее всего, вы найдёте причину.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую.